# Hosted server is not providing any data to Android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

I've been working on an Android project where I want to show all the data those are stored in the database. I've done that part already but the problem is I'm able to get the data from ***localhost*** but when I move to the hosted server it is not giving me any data. I've connected to the server and am able to access the specific php file but it is returning an empty JSON string where there are a of data.

Here is my Connection Class:

```
public class Connecter {

public static HttpURLConnection connect (String urlAddress){

    try {
        URL  url = new URL(urlAddress);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        ///////Setting properties to con object
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        con.setReadTimeout(20000);

        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        ////////Returning the Con object
        return con;


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
    }
}
```

I'm posting using another class.
And here is the process I'm using to pass the url of the specific php file:

```
String address2 = "http://www.tutorshubbd.com/android/allTeacher.php";
    Log.d(TAG," .............///..........Primary Data Display ");
    String query = "";
    SendGetAllTeachers sg2 = new SendGetAllTeachers(ActivityTeacher.this,address2,query,listViewTeachers,ivNoData,ivNoInternet);
    sg2.execute();
```

Here is the specific php file that I'm using:

```html
<?php


$host ='tutorshubbd.com';
$username = 'cpanel_username';
$pwd = 'cpanel_password';
$db = 'tutorshu_db';

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pwd, $db) or die('Unable to connect');

if (mysqli_connect_error($con)) {
 echo "Failed to connect to the DataBase".mysqli_connect_error();

}

$name = $_POST['Query'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM Teacher WHERE Name LIKE '%$name%'";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if ($query) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $data[] = $row;
 }
 print(json_encode($data));

}else{
 echo "Not Found!";
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Here is some additional code where I'm posting and fetching data. (I'm having no trouble fetching data from localhost using this code but putting this just because if you need to see it to figure out the issue).

```
public class SendGetAllTeachers extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

private static final String TAG ="ActivityTeacher";
private Context context;
private String urlAddress;
private String query;
private ListView listView;
private ImageView imageViewNoData, imageViewNoSignal;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public SendGetAllTeachers(Context context, String urlAddress, String query, ListView listView, ImageView...imageViews) {
    this.context = context;
    this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
    this.query = query;
    this.listView = listView;

    this.imageViewNoData=imageViews[0];
    this.imageViewNoSignal=imageViews[1];
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Search:");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Searching for Data...");
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.sendAndReceive();
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    progressDialog.dismiss();

    //RESET LISTVIEW
    listView.setAdapter(null);


    if (s != null){
        if (!s.contains("null")){
            ParserTeacher parserT = new ParserTeacher(context,s,listView);
            parserT.execute();

            imageViewNoData.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            imageViewNoSignal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        }else{
            Log.d(TAG,"......//////////.........///////// Getting Visible ......... NO DATA______AT");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry! No Such Data Exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }else {
        imageViewNoData.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry! Unable to connect to the server.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        imageViewNoSignal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}

private String sendAndReceive(){
    HttpURLConnection con = Connecter.connect(urlAddress);
    if(con == null)
        return null;

    try {
        OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
        Log.d(TAG,"......//////////.........///////// WRITING DATA ......... FIRED______");
        bufferedWriter.write(new DataPackager(query).packageData());

        Log.d(TAG,"......//////////.........///////// NOT WORKING___!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        //Release Resources.
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();


        //Response Code
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        //Decoding response code
        if (responseCode == con.HTTP_OK){

            //Return Data
            InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();

            //Read the returned data...
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            Log.d(TAG,"......//////////.........///////// DATA READ......... FIRED______");
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            if (bufferedReader!=null){
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){

                    response.append(line+"\n");
                }

            }else
                return null;
            return response.toString();

        }else
            return String.valueOf(responseCode);




    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

////////////////////////////////

```
public class DataPackager {

String query;

public DataPackager(String query) {
    this.query = query;
}

public String packageData(){

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    StringBuffer queryStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        jsonObject.put("Query", query);
        Boolean fistValue = true;
        Iterator iterator = jsonObject.keys();

        do {
            String key = iterator.next().toString();
            String value = jsonObject.get(key).toString();

            if (fistValue){
                fistValue = false;
            }else{
                queryStringBuffer.append("&");
            }

            queryStringBuffer.append(URLEncoder.encode(key,"UTF-8"));
            queryStringBuffer.append("=");
            queryStringBuffer.append(URLEncoder.encode(value,"UTF-8"));

        }while (iterator.hasNext());

        return queryStringBuffer.toString();


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}



}
```

///////////////////////////////

```
public class ParserTeacher extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer> {
public static final String TAG = "Parser Teacher";

    private Context c;
    private String data;
    private ListView lv;



    List<GetItems> items = new ArrayList<>();




    public ParserTeacher(Context c, String data, ListView lv) {
        this.c = c;
        this.data = data;
        this.lv = lv;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params){
        return this.parse();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);

        if (integer ==1 ){
            ///////BIND TO LIST VIEW...............................
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(c, items);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);




            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    GetItems sendItem = items.get(i);

                    String name = sendItem.getName();


                    //Snackbar.make(view,"Teachers Detail Mode",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent I = new Intent();
                    I.setClass(view.getContext(),TeachersView.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("Name", name);


                    I.putExtras(extras);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(I);

                }
            });



        }else{
            Log.d(TAG," >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Parsing Error!");
            Toast.makeText(c, "Unable to Parse...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }




    }


    private int parse(){

        try{
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);

            //Log.i("tagconvertstr","............................................\n\n"+ "["+ja+"]");
            JSONObject jo = null;
            items.clear();

            GetItems getItems = null;



            for (int i=0; i<ja.length();i++){
                jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

                String name = jo.getString("Name");



                getItems = new GetItems();

                getItems.setName(name);


                items.add(getItems);

            }

            return 1;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Here is the STACK TRACE.........>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    }
```

(I'm having no trouble fetching data in localhost using this code).

if you load the url you will see that there are a lot of data(could take time to load sometimes) but in the app It is returning an empty string. I'm not using any libraries like volley or retrofit.

I've seen a lot of issues regarding this but this is slightly different from them. I'm being able to connect but not fetch from hosted server but I'm able to fetch from local host.

Comment: `new URL(urlAddress);`. We cannot see what url you use. Further you are not posting anything.

Comment: If we should try your url -with a get- then please post a link.

Comment: the url returns invalid json because you have garbage echos in your php code (the 'header' first line, and the 'DB connected succesfully' echo. remove them. When in doubt, past your so-called json at **[jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)**

Comment: @greenapps here is the url : http://www.tutorshubbd.com/android/allTeacher.php

Comment: You have not posted code where we can see what you POST. Further there is no code where we can see what you read. So we cannot help you.

Comment: `but it is returning an empty JSON string ` Is it? But please start at the begin. What is `sendAndReceive()` returning? `null` ? Which Toast do you see in onPostExecute? You could give some helpfull info about what happens!

Comment: `if(con == null)
        return null;
`. That is not very informative. How would you know that it was this null if it happened?

Comment: @greenapps It is showing Sorry! No such data...
it is returning empty string. 
I'm not sure but I think there is something going on with cross domain thingy.
This same code is working perfect for localhost. not giving data from live server.
Please let me know if you have any more suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: @greenapps : the thing is my php code is printing the Json object on the browser but it is not working in Android.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry! No Such Data Exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }`. You are not showing the contents of s. Change to `Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry! No Such Data Exists: "+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }`

Comment: If it returns an empty sting -as you say- then `if (!s.contains("null"))` would come true and the parser invoked. You would certainly not see the Sorry toast.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160589/discussion-between-tamim-and-greenapps).

Comment: @greenapps
Thank you so much bro.
Just because u said to print that String (s) I did it and the problem was so simple that Server was returning the string with some null so that if was not getting executed and was toasting that message. Just removed that if else and simply parsed and it is working now.
Thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Your response header doesn't have Content-Type values. You have to add to your php code, this line before print the data.

```
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
```